# Should we move the answers to "Hidden features of Google search" to the Google tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

While reviewing some low quality answers I came across this old gem:

[Hidden features of Google Search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-google-search)

Over on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122120/the-great-question-deletion-audit-of-2012) they are discussing, and in some cases implementing, moving the contents of questions like this to the [google](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) or [google-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-search) tag wiki and then deleting the question as they don't really fit the Stack Exchange Q&A model.

Do people think that it would be a good idea to clean up this question in the same way?

Are there any other questions that would benefit from the same treatment?

Answer (score 6):

Most of those "Hidden features" type polls are junk and don't really serve any purpose other than being there.

It would a nice experiment on traffic if you could just dump that into the tag repo and nominate to the search engines where the 301 should go when you delete the question.

All those "Alternative to X" and "I like this, but not like this" and "Recommend me an app that does jurgo woggle" could all just be closed and their respective tags include:

- Tag list of web apps people are actually using as alternatives
- Notes on how to better their search and where they should look at instead of using another Stack Exchange site as their butler, peeling grapes and serving them up a directory they're too lazy to look at in the first place.

So an example question:

> #### Is there a web app that watches movies for me and tickles my cat about the changes in plane ticket prices?
>
> I be unable to prone myself without the need to know what deals I be losing out on a one-way trip to the Bermuda Trianglez. There is be a web app that will as the title says?
>
> Peace be to love with Bone Thugs-n-Harmony
>
> tagged: movies, webapp-rec, travel

In each of the respective tag wikis you'd have:

- [movies](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movies) and [travel](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel) - List of tags of apps that centre around movies and travel respectively. If there are no tags with such apps, then no one is using them, no need to list them.
- [webapp-rec](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webapp-rec) - Taken out back and destroyed. Or links in the tag repo to Alternative.To, GetApp.com, etc.

Comment: That is brilliant. I only wish I had more up votes to give. Your sample question made me laugh in public. The webapp-rec tag recommendation about being taken out back and destroyed resonates strongly as well.